# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Label2.'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, debugging

Here's the exact error message I got:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< Deetox.StoreViewController 0x102640610 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Label2.'`

I created an info button which is suppose to take the user to the Store page of my app but when I tap on the info button it crashes. Do you guys know why? And how can I fix it? Thanks a lot! ;)

Here's my code on StoreViewController:

```
import UIKit

import StoreKit

class StoreViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    }

    @IBOutlet var Label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BuyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var ProductTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ProductDescription: UITextView!

    var Product: SKProduct?
    var ProductID = "co.AytacEren.Deetox.RemoveAds"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Label1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        Button1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        Button2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        BuyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        BuyButton.isEnabled = false
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        getPurchaseInfo()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func DismissView(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func Purchase(_ sender: Any) {

        let Payment = SKPayment(product: Product!)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(Payment)

    }

    @IBAction func Restore(_ sender: Any) {

        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

    }


    func getPurchaseInfo() {

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.ProductID) as! Set<String>)

            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

        }

        else {

            ProductTitle.text = "Warning"
            ProductDescription.text = "Please enable In-App Purchase in your settings"

        }

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        var products = response.products

        if (products.count == 0) {

            ProductTitle.text = "Warning"
            ProductDescription.text = "Product not found"

        }

        else {

            Product = products [0]
            ProductTitle.text = Product!.localizedTitle
            ProductDescription.text = Product?.localizedDescription
            BuyButton.isEnabled = true

        }

        let Invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

        for Product in Invalids {

            print("Product not found: \(Product)")

        }

    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction in transactions {

            switch transaction.transactionState {

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                ProductTitle.text = "Thank you"
                ProductDescription.text = "You have purchased the product"
                BuyButton.isEnabled = false

                let save = UserDefaults.standard
                save.set(true, forKey: "Purchase")
                save.synchronize()

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                ProductTitle.text = "Thank you"
                ProductDescription.text = "You have purchased the product"
                BuyButton.isEnabled = false

                let save = UserDefaults.standard
                save.set(true, forKey: "Purchase")
                save.synchronize()

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                ProductTitle.text = "Warning"
                ProductDescription.text = "You have not purchased the product"

            default:
                break
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your storyboard right click on the button. You should seen an outlet called `Label2`. Delete it, and you should be fine.

This usually happens when you have an outlet that is connected to your code, but then you either delete/rename the outlet in your code and forget to delete it from the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! It helped me a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your storyboard / xib for StoreViewController. Basically there is a broken link where you have a `Label2` supposedly connected to the ViewController but it is not there in code. `@IBOutlet Label2` either got deleted, renamed or is commented out.

What you can do to fix it is remove that broken link from the Storyboard or Xib by right-clicking the the element that was once Label2 and removing the reference from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked for me! ;)

Comment: You are welcome @AytacEren! That happens way too often... haha. :D